# No visual content after running report in Excel

Tags: excel, stored-procedures, sas

I am trying to run a Stored Process from the SAS tab in Excel (Reports button). After running it, I get the following message: "Stored Process has completed with no visual content. You can refresh this analysis through the Manage Content dialog box". Below you can see my code:

```
ods excel;



create table DAI as
select DISTINCT (A.V_NUMBER), B.PHRDEDN_APPLICABLE_GROSS
from UVICRPT.V_HRS_PAYROLL_PHRHIST A, UVICRPT.V_HRS_PAYROLL_PHRDEDN B
WHERE A.PHRHIST_DISP in ('70')
AND A.PHRHIST_PAYNO = &PayNo AND B.PHRDEDN_PAYNO = &PayNo
AND A.PHRHIST_PICT_CODE = "&PictCode" AND B.PHRDEDN_PICT_CODE = "&PictCode"
AND A.PHRHIST_YEAR = B.PHRDEDN_YEAR
AND A.PHRHIST_SEQ_NO = B.PHRDEDN_SEQ_NO;
run;



ods excel options(sheet_interval="table" sheet_name="Koala");
proc print data=DAI style=Table noobs;
run;

ods excel close;

QUIT;
```

All I want is a new sheet in the book I'm working on named "Koala" with the table displayed.

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Comment: Can you see the log? I suspect SAS is creating a file iwht this and storing it somewhere else. What happens if you remove the ODS statements entirely.